# Windows 10 Constant Weird Audio Peeps

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

I woke up today and turned on my computer to hear some extreemly strange noises. I opened sound control panel to find that the noises are in fact coming from windows because I see the green Levels going up. Maybe this is a software problem? I recently installed meshroom.

Any help is appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hQVntHR-7S6LHZtb64bvODqxy2C6MI1X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can open the Windows volume mixer (e.g. via sound tray icon), there you can see each application and the volume bars if it plays a sound.

Comment: A screenshot of the control panel you speak of would be appreciated.  Please use the upload image functionality instead of using Google Drive.